# save all textfields by clicking on one update button

Tags: javascript, php, database, magento

we have magento site. we are giving option for vendor to edit all textfields of multiple products and save all by clicking one "**Update**" button.

we are using following code for saving price of one text field.

**Price**

```
public function updateFieldPriceAction(){
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);      
    $id= $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $customerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
    $collection_product = Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$id))->addFieldToFilter('userid',array('eq'=>$customerid));
    //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setEditProductId($id);

    try{
    $upd_price = $this->getRequest()->getParam('price');
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);        
    //$product->setData('price', $upd_price);
    $product->setPrice($upd_price);

    //$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($id);
    //$stockItem->setData('manage_stock', 1);
    //$stockItem->setData('qty', $this->getRequest()->getParam('qty'));
    $product->save();

    echo $price = $product->getPrice();
    echo $name = $product->getName();

    $response['message'] = 'Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated';
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response)); 
    //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated'));


    //endif;
    }catch(Exception $e){
    echo "Not Saving"; exit;    
    Mage::log($e->getMessage());
    }

  }
```

we are using following code to save quantity of one text field.

**Quantity**

```
public function updateFieldAction(){
        $id= $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $customerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        $collection_product = Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$id))->addFieldToFilter('userid',array('eq'=>$customerid));
        //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setEditProductId($id);
        $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($id);
        $stockItem->setData('manage_stock', 1);
        $stockItem->setData('qty', $this->getRequest()->getParam('qty'));

        $stockItem->save();

        $response['message'] = 'Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated';
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response)); 
        //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated'));
      }
```

we are using following code to save all textfields of price and quantity by **single update button**. Price is working. but quantity is not working.

**controller.php**

```
public function massupdatesellerproAction(){
    if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
        if(!$this->_validateFormKey()){
             $this->_redirect('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/');
        }
        $ids= $this->getRequest()->getParam('product_mass_update');
        $price= $this->getRequest()->getParam('price');
        $qty = $this->getRequest()->getParam('qty');
        foreach ($ids as $key => $value) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($value);
    $product->setPrice($price[$key]);
    $product->setQty($qty[$key]);
    $product->save();
        }
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess( Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Products has been sucessfully saved from your account'));
        $this->_redirect('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/');


    }}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setQty` not working in magento. quantity generally save on stock not in product. remove

```
$product->setQty($qty[$key]);
```

from your controller.

This is a partial answer, but hopefully it sends you in the right direction.
You can try to save quantity by below code in controller.php

```
 $product->setStockData(
   array( 
          'is_in_stock' => 1, 
          'qty' => $qty[$key],
          'manage_stock' => 1,
          'use_config_notify_stock_qty' => 1
   )
 );
```

or
you can
Try this **controller.php** instead:

```
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product);
$stockItem->setData('qty', $this->getRequest()->getParam('qty'));
$stockItem->save();
$product->save();
```

and then set and save your changes as before.
you can check [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1446/how-to-set-a-product-to-be-in-out-of-stock-programatically).

this is your full function for quantity update

```
public function updateFieldAction(){
        $id= $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $customerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        $collection_product = Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$id))->addFieldToFilter('userid',array('eq'=>$customerid));
        //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setEditProductId($id);
        $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($id);
        $stockItem->setData('manage_stock', 1);
        $stockItem->setData('qty', $this->getRequest()->getParam('qty'));

        $stockItem->save();
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load( 'id' );
        $product->save();

        $response['message'] = 'Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated';
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response)); 
        //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated'));
      }
```

controller code

```
public function massupdatesellerproAction(){
if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
    if(!$this->_validateFormKey()){
         $this->_redirect('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/');
    }
    $ids= $this->getRequest()->getParam('product_mass_update');
    $price= $this->getRequest()->getParam('price');
    $qty = $this->getRequest()->getParam('qty');
    foreach ($ids as $key => $value) {
     $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($value);
     $product->setPrice($price[$key]);
     $product->setStockData(
       array( 
        'is_in_stock' => 1, 
        'qty' => $qty[$key],
        'manage_stock' => 1,
        'use_config_notify_stock_qty' => 1
       )
    );


     $product->save();
    }
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess( Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Products has been sucessfully saved from your account'));
    $this->_redirect('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/');


}}
```

Comment: i am trying this controller.php = > http://pastebin.com/9zLVnpFA but its not working

Comment: set  $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product); after declaring $product within foreach loop

Comment: can you please give me complete  "public function massupdatesellerproAction()" code

Comment: i wil check and let you know. some problem happened here in live site.

Comment: please help me ehre : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35628694/quantity-is-not-updating-in-magento-site/35645699#35645699